# Guidelines for creating an index

Tags: indexing, best-practices

This is not necessarily a LaTeX-only question, and it is a bit open-ended, but given that this community is clearly very detail-oriented, and it is a general-interest question, I think that this is a good place to ask this question.

I'm currently finishing up writing a 700-page mathematical text book*, and the time has come to create an index. I was wondering if you guys have any ideas on guidelines on how to create an index. I will be using `makeindex` (unless anyone has a better alternative; I'm definitely open for suggestions).

I have a decently clear idea on what keywords to put in there, but I have some remaining issues:

- What are the rules for making subentries? For example, should "open set" appear in the index as  "open set", or as "set -> open"? (`set!open` in makeindex syntax).
- What about using "*see ...*". For example, I have an index entry "Linear optimization model". It make sense to have two entries: "linear -> optimization model", and "optimization model -> linear". Should one of them refer to the other using a "*see ...*"? Or is it preferred to just refer to the same page number from both entries?

Any other thoughts are also very welcome.

---

*) In LaTeX, obviously. I'm taking the liberty here to thank many of you here at `tex.stackexchange.com` that have answered my questions; the community will definitely be mentioned in the acknowledgements.

Comment: In my analysis books, open set is part of open covering and set refers to set algebra not open or closed sets  By mine, I mean books I own not written.

Comment: Sometime ago, **egreg** wrote an excellent blog entry: [(Don’t) forget to run MakeIndex](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/dont-forget-to-run-makeindex/). Recommendation: read the article and switch to [`imakeidx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx). Take into account also that an index is one of the most fundamental parts of a book; a good index is a phenomenal resource; a poor index is disastrous.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for that reference, that's very helpful! I'm still keen to hear some opinions about best practices on organizing the actual index though.

Comment: The "Oxford Style Manual" has a good chapter on indexing. With regard to things like `\index{open set}` or `\index{set!open}` it depends on how many other `set` sub-entries you'll likely to have. If it's the only one, I'd leave it as a main entry. With regard to cross-referencing the OSM recommends not using a cross-reference if the "see blah" part takes up more space than the location list.